# maven compilation fails because unavailable dependency

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to run java program with maven but when i compiled using the command mvn -U compile
he shows me the following error

```
[root@onePK-EFT1 tutorials]# mvn -U compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                        
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building onePK Java Tutorials 0.6.0.5
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/cisco/onep/libonep-core-rel
/0.6.0.5/libonep-core-rel-0.6.0.5.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.cisco.onep:libonep-core-rel:jar:0.6.0.5 is missing, no 
dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/cisco/onep/libonep-
core-rel/0.6.0.5/libonep-core-rel-0.6.0.5.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.517s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 09 07:28:28 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java-tutorials: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project com.cisco.onep:java-tutorials:jar:0.6.0.5: Could not find 
artifact com.cisco.onep:libonep-core-rel:jar:0.6.0.5 in central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read
 the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN   
/DependencyResolutionException
```

and this is my pom.xml file

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  
 /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.cisco.onep</groupId>
<artifactId>hello-network-app</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>The onePK Hello Network Example Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cisco.onep</groupId>
        <artifactId>libonep-core-rel</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>onePK Team</name>
        <email>onepk-feedback@cisco.com</email>
        <organization>Cisco.com</organization>
    </developer>
</developers>
```

I think it's because he can't find libonep-core-rel.jar which i have it included 
please any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use the appropriate maven repository for the artifacts `com.cisco.onep*` which are not located in Maven central.

Comment: how can i tell maven to not download the jar that he can find it in a file on my disk

Comment: Start using a repository manager and deploy the artifact manually into the repository manager. This is the simplest and most reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As an immediate solution, but not a recommendation, you can use [system dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) to resolve artifacts on your local filesystem.

As @khmarbaise implied, try to publish those corporate artifacts to your corporate Maven repository (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva, etc.), even an FTP/HTTP server would do...

Once you publish those corporate artifacts to your "corporate" repository(hopefully it's already in place), you just need a [new repository declaration](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) in your Maven POM.